# Solution to multiple linear equalities (3a = 2b = 4c etc)

Tags: linear-algebra

When given 2a = 3b = c = 5d, how should one find a, b, c, d given that all values are positive and sum up to 1? (a, b, c, d > 0 & a + b + c + d = 1)

The answer is 15/61, 10/61, 30/61, 6/61 but I'm not sure how to get there.

Comment: The answer you have been given assumes in addition that $a + b + c + d = 1$.

Comment: Yep, thanks - I've edited the question to reflect that now. I'm solving for a probability distribution here, which is why the sum needs to be 1.

Comment: Express $a,b,d$ is terms of $c$. Then set the sum to $1$ and solve for $c$.